# Union duplicate members

Tags: c, naming-conventions, unions, algebra

My latest program in C needs to deal with simple algebra. When creating a union to which my basic understanding is that only one value can be initialized (sorry for my crude/rough explanations), I was surprised to see that I could not have variables with different data types named the same. Here is the code:

```
typedef union
{
    int val;
    Unknown val;
}Value;
```

Here is the error:

```
In file included from grid.c:5:0:
line.h:9:10: error: duplicate member ‘val’
  Unknown val;
```

Am I just making beginner assumptions? If so why is it necessary to keep variable names unique in a union.
Thanks for taking the time to read.
EDIT:
Just in case:

```
typedef struct
{
    char label;
}Unknown;
```

Comment: union in `C` is a namespace. You can't have duplicate names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the wrong assumption to assume two different variable types can be named the same thing. A problem will arise when you try to set an integer or a data of type `Unkown` equal to val. The program won't know if you are referring to the val of type Unknown or int (it doesn't magically figure it out for you). Hence, it is better to name it different things. Also, it is better naming convention to name things that aptly represent what they will be set equal to.